# Magento 1.7 Directory Separator returning wrong seperator

Tags: magento-1.7, image

I'm trying to get a function working to re size any image using a custom module and helper class. For the record I'm running this on a local XAMPP server.

If I pass a image url and a destination url using '/' all works fine. However I need to implement this with DS for future proofing. The following is an example line of code I'm using. with the DS instead of '/'

```
$newPath = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . DS . "resized" . DS . $fileName;
```

This returns (without the http or localhost at the start because stackoverflow doesn't allow that even in code) "/test/media/resized\catalog\category\testcat.jpg"

How do I make it so that DS correctly returns forward slashes?

Comment: DS is `directory` separator. You should use it to build `path to file`. You shouldn't use it to build image `URL`.

Comment: @Zyava - The OP is using `Mage::getBaseDir` - not `getSkinUrl` - he is looking to get the path to image - not the URL for the image

Comment: I would say, the error is in the database and the dump is from windows.

Comment: I am confused. It looks like the OP wants to say that the line returns `http://localhost/test/media/resized\catalog\category\testcat.jpg` but he had problems to write that on stackexchange??? But getBaseDir does not add a http:// ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no reason at all to change the `DS`.

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a [predefined PHP constant](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) that is set by your PHP installation itself.

If it is returning the wrong value, it is because your PHP installation is wrong.

Don't adjust Magento to suit a broken PHP install.

Answer (score 5):

This is strictly speaking correct for Windows systems.
You probably have to set `DS` hardcoded, in `app/Mage.php` change

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

to

```
define('DS', '/');
```